# Creating instances in loop freezes app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a movie clip exported for ActionScript as a class and I am creating many instances from it inside a loop and adding it to stage.
when I test the app on mobile, it freezes for a second when the loop starts and then everything works back.
The following is an example of how it looks:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
   var mc:MC = new MC();
   mc.textField.text = "mc"+i;
   mc.y = i * mc.height;
   addChild(mc);
}
```

So, I am asking if there is a better way to do it without freezing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to improve the performance would be to utilize the *"[object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)"* to reuse the already generated objects over time:

> It is a software creational design pattern that uses a set of
>   initialized objects kept ready to use – a "pool" – rather than
>   allocating and destroying them on demand. A client of the pool will
>   request an object from the pool and perform operations on the returned
>   object. When the client has finished, it returns the object to the
>   pool rather than destroying it; this can be done manually or
>   automatically.

More information and a working sample code on the *"object pool pattern"* is available on the [Adobe's website](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-19cd3c2412513c24bce-8000.html) :)

Comment: Thanks that a pretty much what i was looking for

Comment: very useful reference,  `Optimizing Performance` articles , tnx